# Why after upgrading to Lubuntu 12.10 from 12.04 I can't login other than using the "Guest Account"?

Tags: 12.10, lubuntu

Why after upgrading to Lubuntu 12.10 from 12.04 I can't login other than using the "Guest Account". On the login screen there is the option for "Guest Account" and "Other...".

I select "Other..." and type in the [administrator] user name and password I just used in the install [the original user name & password from 12.04] and it keeps on giving me the message "Incorrect password, please try again".

I have tried reinstalling with a different user name and password without any success.  The only option I haven't tried yet is to set it to "Auto Login" during the install.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/24024/46312 should do it

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)

Comment: First you're saying "after *upgrading* to Lubuntu 12.10 from 12.04" and then you mention "I have tried reinstalling..." - so what's the current state of things? If you re-installed the system obviously your old login and password won't work, the one you specified during the (most recent) install will.

Comment: As I logically said before. I upgraded then I've re-installed because it willnot accecpt the password I just used in the in stall Also I can't login from terminal [ctrl+alt+F1] or from within "Guest Account" to access or change file/drives. Thx Arie

Comment: As I logically said before. I upgraded then I've re-installed because it will not accept the password I just used in the install. Obviously I use the UM & PW that I entered during that install. All I mentioned is that the UN & PW I used the first time was the UN & PW I was using for 12.04! Also I can't login from terminal [ctrl+alt+F1] or from within "Guest Account" to access or change file/drives. Thx Arie

Comment: Is this a bug or what because no matter what UN & PW I use during install it won't accept the same combination after!

Comment: Reset PW & noticed that it would not accept my UN. so i left UN blank then it worked. But now when I login it just shows me a screen of multicolored letters when i"m back @ the login screen...??? thx Arie

Comment: I am wondering if it could be the keymapping confusing things. Have you looked into this?